# Decimal separator in an HTML Input form

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

I am having a problem with a project.

I want to have a decimal separator after the last 2 digits of the value.
E.g. 4500 in the database should be output as 45.00

Now what I want to do is visualize this in a form which a user will fill. However currently it not only visualizes it but it also tries to input it in the database with the separator addition and it returns an error. The table in the mysql is integer.

The code:

Form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('price', 'Price:') !!}
 {!! Form::text('price', null, array('class'=>'form-price', 'lang'=>'en-150', 'placeholder'=>'0.00', 'data-type'=>'currency')) !!}
 </div>
```

JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("input[data-type='currency']").on({
keyup: function() {
formatCurrency($(this));
},
blur: function() { 
formatCurrency($(this), "blur");
}
});


function formatNumber(n) {
// format number 1000000 to 1,234,567
return n.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "")
}


function formatCurrency(input, blur) {
// appends $ to value, validates decimal side
// and puts cursor back in right position.

// get input value
var input_val = input.val();

// don't validate empty input
if (input_val === "") { return; }

// original length
var original_len = input_val.length;

// initial caret position 
var caret_pos = input.prop("selectionStart");

// check for decimal
if (input_val.indexOf(".") >= 0) {

// get position of first decimal
// this prevents multiple decimals from
// being entered
var decimal_pos = input_val.indexOf(".");

// split number by decimal point
var left_side = input_val.substring(0, decimal_pos);
var right_side = input_val.substring(decimal_pos);

// add commas to left side of number
left_side = formatNumber(left_side);

// validate right side
right_side = formatNumber(right_side);

// On blur make sure 2 numbers after decimal
if (blur === "blur") {
  right_side += "00";
}

// Limit decimal to only 2 digits
right_side = right_side.substring(0, 2);

// join number by .
input_val = left_side + "." + right_side;

} else {
// no decimal entered
// add commas to number
// remove all non-digits
input_val = formatNumber(input_val);
input_val = input_val;

// final formatting
if (blur === "blur") {
  input_val += ".00";
}
}

// send updated string to input
input.val(input_val);

// put caret back in the right position
var updated_len = input_val.length;
caret_pos = updated_len - original_len + caret_pos;
input[0].setSelectionRange(caret_pos, caret_pos);
}
</script>
```

So how do I make it so when I input 45.00 in the Form input and click submit to insert 4500 in the database. Because in this form the code is trying to insert the value as decimal (45.00) and since it's an integer in mysql it returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) section in the docs.

> Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attribute values
>   when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

In your case this could be something like this:

```
// In your model.

public function setPriceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = $value * 100; //$value in dollar
}
```

And to get the value in the proper format, you set an accessor.

```
// In your model.

public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return number_format($this->price / 100, 2);
}
```